# Erro de conversão String em JSONArray - Método Volley Android

Tags: java, c#, android, json, volley

Minha aplicação recebe uma JSONString via web service de uma API C#, como listada abaixo:

```
[{
"LimiteCredito": 123.00,
"PessoasFuncionarioId": 16,
"Id": 12,
"Nome": "Cliente PF A",
"DataEdicao": "\/Date(1485019536610-0200)\/",
"UsuarioAlteracaoId": "cdf23118-5991-4eb5-9ec4-ea1fc6e6ce3a",
"RazaoSocial": "Cliente PF A",
"Tipo": 1,
"Cpf": "80158536991   ",
"Sexo": "M",
"TelefonePrincipal": "(41) 9999-9999",
"Email": "comercial@datasig.com.br",
"EstadoRgId": 2,
"Apelido": "Cliente PF A",
"Erp10Id": 1,
"GrupoCrCpId": 1
}]
```

Ao tentar converter esta `JSONString` para `JSONArray`, recebo uma `org.json.JSONException` com o seguinte erro:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"LimiteCredito": 123.00,
"PessoasFuncionarioId": 16,
"Id": 12,
"Nome": "Cliente PF A",
"DataEdicao": "\/Date(1485019536610-0200)\/",
"UsuarioAlteracaoId": "cdf23118-5991-4eb5-9ec4-ea1fc6e6ce3a",
"RazaoSocial": "Cliente PF A",
"Tipo": 1,
"Cpf": "80158536991   ",
"Sexo": "M",
"TelefonePrincipal": "(41) 9999-9999",
"Email": "comercial@datasig.com.br",
"EstadoRgId": 2,
"Apelido": "Cliente PF A",
"Erp10Id": 1,
"GrupoCrCpId": 1
}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Segue abaixo meu código usando a biblioteca Volley.
- Código que chama a Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste_requisicao);

    url = "minhaURL";
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(TesteRequisicaoActivity.this);


    callByJsonArrayRequest(null);
}

// CALLS VOLLEY
public void callByJsonArrayRequest(View view) {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("UserName", "demo");
    params.put("Password", "12341234");

    RegrasClienteMixForteHelper request = new RegrasClienteMixForteHelper(Request.Method.POST, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.i("Script", "SUCCESS: " + response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(TesteRequisicaoActivity.this, "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    request.setTag("tag");
    queue.add(request);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    queue.cancelAll("tag");
}
```

- Código que chama o método de recebimento dos dados JSONArray:

  ```
  public class RegrasClienteMixForteHelper extends Request<JSONArray> {
  private Response.Listener<JSONArray> response;
  private Map<String, String> params;

  public RegrasClienteMixForteHelper(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params, Response.Listener<JSONArray> response, Response.ErrorListener listener) {
              super(method, url, listener);
              this.params = params;
              this.response = response;}




  public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
      return params;
  }

  public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
      HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
      header.put("apiKey", "application/json");

      return (header);
  }

  @Override
  protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
      try {

          String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
          JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);// ERROR -> this is not a JSONArray, same for JSONObject
          return Response.success(jsonArray, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
  }


  @Override
  protected void deliverResponse(JSONArray response) {
      this.response.onResponse(response);
  }
  ```

O que há de errado no código para não conseguir fazer a conversão para JSONArray?

Comment: Cara, voce consegue debugar e ver se o valor da variável **jsonString** é exatamente a que mostra ali no erro? Testei aqui, e ele conseguiu montar o  **JSON** de boa!

Comment: Thiago, muito obrigado pelo seu teste.  Desta forma analisamos os dados enviados e o problema estava na formatação de algumas informações enviadas para o dispositivo Android.  Foi somente a formatação da data.  Agora esta funcionando.

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?